# ember-cli sinon.js xhr tests examples?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, sinon

So, I want to test the XHR requests on an ember-cli app, After endless googling/searching, I couldn't find a good resource/test suites that explains/shows how to use sinon's `fakeServer` or `useFakeXMLHttpRequest`, most of the examples shows you some very basic tests with fake data.

Are there any real examples/projects I could look at to learn from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I usually don't use sinon ...assuming you want to see *any* xhr stub test w/ ember I threw together one with fauxjax https://github.com/toranb/pods-with-components-example/blob/master/tests/acceptance/customers-test.js#L16-L24

Comment: fyi - I use fauxjax because when combined w/ this module https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-test-helpers/blob/master/test-support/helpers/module.js I can see when my test xhrs don't match (any why they don't so I can fix them /do legit tdd)

Comment: (last comment I promise) -this test shows how that special qunit module works https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-test-helpers/blob/master/tests/unit/module-test.js#L26-L36

Comment: Have you looked at pretender for testing your XHR requets?  https://github.com/trek/pretender  There's also an Ember CLI wrapper: https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-pretender

Comment: @ToranBillups Himself replying to me!! You can write as much comments as you want :D, Thanks for the tips, I will try that!

Comment: No @kielni I haven't actually, I will give it a shot if fauxjax did not work for me, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Mawaheb haha, only one Toran Billups I know so in that case :) yes indeed (let me know how the fauxjax stuff goes)

Comment: @ToranBillups Thanks for caring!, Actually I switched back to sinon, Did not have much luck with FauxJax, Even though it's as simple as this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/350e258fa9e1f7da85dd
the test keeps sending requests to the backEnd, and I get 401 error

But, With Sinon, The test is passing, No backEnd requests were made:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58e52518210bd558d1c5

I will be working on a websocket test in the near future, if you have any suggesting, please feel free to write as much comments as you want :D

Comment: @Mawaheb understood -and honestly fauxjax is a $.ajax interceptor (not a fit for WS work/etc)